# ios: UI hang on multiple download thread using afnetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

[image]i am working on multiple images download. but after sometime my ui hangs and memory constantly increases.

i am using afnetworking for downloading the images.

```
-(void)download:(NSString *)url
{

NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [SessionManager downloadTaskWithRequest:request progress:nil destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response) {
    NSURL *documentsDirectoryURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:YES error:nil];
    documentsDirectoryURL = [documentsDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Assets"];
    return [documentsDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[response suggestedFilename]];
} completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error) {
    //NSLog(@"File downloaded to: %@", filePath);
    [[ePackDownloader sharedClient] downloadComplete:url];
}];

[downloadTask resume];
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to  `[[ePackDownloader sharedClient] downloadComplete:url];` call on the main thread?

Comment: yes i have tried this